# comparing two angles

Tags: math, vector, geometry

Given four points in the plane, `A,B,X,Y`, I wish to determine which of the following two  angles is smaller `∢ABX` or `∢ABY`.

The angle `∢ABX` is defined as the angle of `BX`, when `AB` is translated to lie on the open segment `(-∞,0]`. Intuitively when saying `∢ABX` I mean the angle you get when you turn left after visiting vertex `B`.

I'd rather not use `cos` or `sqrt`, in order to preserve accuracy, and to maximize performance (the code would run on an embedded system).

In the case where `A=(-1,0),B=(0,0)`, I can compare the two angles `∢ABX` and `∢ABY`, by calculating the dot product of the vectors `X,Y`, and watch its sign.

What I can do in this case is:

1. Determine whether or not `ABX` turns right or left
2. If `ABX` turns left check whether or not `Y` and `A` are on the same side of the line on segment `BX`. If they are - `∢ABX` is a smaller than `ABY`.
3. If `ABX` turns right, then `Y` and `A` on the same side of `BX` means that `∢ABX` is larger than `∢ABY`.

But this seems too complicated to me.

Any simpler approach?

Comment: Note that preserving accuracy only makes sense if your positions are already known exactly, e.g. represented as integers or rational numbers.

But there are other legitimate reasons for avoiding square roots, namely performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudocode. Doesn't detect the case when both angles are the same. Also doesn't deal with angle orientation, e.g. assumes all angles are <= 180 degrees.

```
v0 = A-B
v1 = X-B
v2 = Y-B

dot1 = dot(v0, v1)
dot2 = dot(v0, v2)

if(dot1 > 0)
  if(dot2 < 0)
    // ABX is smaller
  if(dot1 * dot1 / dot(v1,v1) > dot2 * dot2 / dot(v2, v2) )
    // ABX is smaller
  // ABY is smaller

if(dot2 > 0)
  // ABY is smaller
if(dot1 * dot1 / dot(v1,v1) > dot2 * dot2 / dot(v2,v2) )
  // ABY is smaller
// ABX is smaller
```

Note that much of this agonizing pain goes away if you allow taking two square roots.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Rational Trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry).  The ideas of distance and angle are replaced by quadrance and spread, which don't involve `sqrt` and `cos`.  See the bottom of that webpage to see how spread between two lines is calculated.  The subject has its own website and even a [youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/njwildberger).

Answer (score 0):

Use the law of cosines: `a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b*cos(phi) = c**2`

where a = |ax|, b =|bx| (|by|), c=|ab| (|ay|) and phi is your angle ABX (ABY)

Comment: How do you get these distances without sqrt?

Comment: The idea of "no square root" has to go.

Comment: You don't need sqrt. You compare the cos(phi1) with cos(phi2). THe larger of the two is the larger angle.

Comment: Really?  What do you do about the discontinuity at x = 0?

Comment: You will need sqrt to compute the `2*a*b` term (which you need to do to solve for `cos(phi)`). Also, the larger of `cos(phi1)`, `cos(phi2)` will correspond to the *smaller* angle.

Answer (score 0):

Center the origin on B by doing

```
X = X - B
Y = Y - B
A = A - B
```

**EDIT**: you also need to normalise the 3 vectors

```
A = A / |A|
X = X / |X|
Y = Y / |Y|
```

Find the two angles by doing

```
acos(A dot X)
acos(A dot Y)
```

===

I don't understand the point of the loss of precision. You are just comparing, not modifying in any way the coordinates of the points...

Comment: You have assumed that the magnitudes of A and X are 1 (or reciprocals of each other). The same goes for A and Y.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get away without using sqrt.
Simple:

```
AB = A-B/|A-B|
XB = X-B/|X-B|
YB = Y-B/|Y-B|

if(dot(XB,AB) > dot (YB,AB)){
 //<ABY is grater
}
else
{
...
}
```

Comment: I described an approach in the question which doesn't use square root. I'll be glad to hear why won't my approach work.

Answer (score -1):

> I'd rather not use cos or sqrt, in order to preserve accuracy.

This makes no sense whatsoever.

> But this seems too complicated to me.

This seems utterly wrong headed to me.

Take the difference between two vectors and look at the signs of the components.

The thing you'll have to be careful about is what "smaller" means.  That idea isn't very precise as stated. For example, if one point A is in quadrant 4 (x-component > 0 and y-component < 0) and the other point B is in quadrant 1 (x-component > 0 and y-component > 0), what does "smaller" mean?  The angle of the vector from the origin to A is between zero and π/2; the angle of the vector from the origin to B is between 3π/4 and 2π.  Which one is "smaller"?

Comment: That's a good point. The angle `∢ABX` is defined as the angle of `BX`, when `AB` is translated to lie on the open segment (-∞,0]. Intuitively I mean the angle `ABX` when you turn left after visiting vertex `B`.

Comment: Cos is an approximation, so yes, some accuracy is lost in addition to high cost of those operation. In addition, he only need monotone function not value itself.